# QString compare with digits

Tags: c++, compare, qstring

I'm looking for a comparison function between QString that take in account digits.
For example:

```
std::vector<QString> init { "test22", "test4", "test1", "test10", "test2" };
```

If I use basic QString::compare, it sorts the list like:

```
"test1", "test10", "test2", "test22", "test4"
```

But I'd like the list to be sorted like:

```
"test1", "test2", "test4", "test10", "test22"
```

In Win32 API, it corresponds to the function [StrCmpLogicalW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SHLWAPI%2FStrCmpLogicalW);k(StrCmpLogicalW);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true), but I'm looking for the equivalent with QString.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at QCollator, specifically http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcollator.html#setNumericMode

Comment: Thanks for the QCollator reference. It does the job. I think QString::compare() documentation should reference this class.